# How to configure WSO2 ESB 4.7 JMS consumer proxy polling interval?

Tags: jms, wso2, esb, polling, consumer

Can anyone tell me if there is a property that allows one to configure how often a JMS consumer proxy polls a queue/topic?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think such a mechanism available. Generally if a message comes to a queue its get removed by the listener. The time between removing an element and next element is variable and  depends on several other factors.

But you can achieve this by having two queues. You can create a thread to move a message from one queue to another in a scheduled time. So in the second queue, a message is available only in particular time interval.